# jquery + css animate in browser issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm new to js, and want two animated menus on a page. 
I have an example here, but have 2 issues. 
http://jsfiddle.net/misemefein/k3dKz/5/ 
1: I want the menu div's to be off screen on page load and slide in on relevant click. 
  it is currently the other way round. 
2: the animation is working in jsfiddle, but not on a test page in browser: http://bit.ly/M7TZrt

any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. Position the elements outside the body with css, jsfiddle:
   http://jsfiddle.net/k3dKz/6/

Stil need to update the click event for girls, to animate the other direction.

1. You're not linking jQuery in this website, your console says '$ is not defined', make sure you load jQuery, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may change your JavsScript as well as CSS. Your CSS and `animate()` function is not positioning elements well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideboys button').click(function() {
        var $lefty = $(this).next();
        $lefty.animate({
          left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
          -$lefty.outerWidth() :
          0
        });
  });
  $('#slidegirls button').click(function() {
        var $righty = $(this).next();
        $righty.animate({
          right: parseInt($righty.css('right'),10) == 0 ?
          -$righty.outerWidth() :
          0
        });
  });
});
```

Here is the corrected working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k3dKz/7/

Also add this line;

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
```

or

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
```

inside the `<header>` portion of your web page to make your code run.

Hope this helps...

Comment: sorry so stupid of me to not link jquery. however this does not resolve the issue in browser. this is your edit + jq-1.4.2 http://bit.ly/M0OfV3

Comment: now i understand that u r a beginner. You are not wrapping the code inside document.ready function, and u just copied the code from fiddle. The code in fiddle is already wrapped inside document ready function by the site itself (you can see in a drop-down at left), so no need for us to nest it again. But when you use the code, use the code i PASTED in the answer here.

Comment: ah yes. I understand now. I brought your edit into my file, but via fiddle which removed the document.ready function. thanks very much you solved the issue.